# I've been getting weird colour schemes for different programs on windows 10

Tags: windows-10

So whenever I start up my laptop, in different programs/applications I open, the colour scheme is messed up, the writing is unreadable, probably due to the background colour, and it has only applied to windows programs as well as google chrome, i've found that it will apply to random windows program and chrome. PLease help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9Vx2.png)